# AngulaJs Date format on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code and it returns a nice date format in the `html` part but I need to return the same format in the `JavaScript` "controller" part.

```
function Ctrl($scope)
{
$scope.date = new Date();

}
```

view:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}

</div>
```

Return: `2016-07-09 00:14:09`

So I want to return the same format in `console.log();`
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if I am correct you are getting filtered data in HTML and want same at JS side. Use _$scope.date = $filter('date')($scope.date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');_ in your js.

Comment: Yes, exactly. thanks for quick response. let me check

Comment: I got this error:  ReferenceError: $filter is not defined

Comment: define $filter as a dependency in controller that's it. I don't think this problem can worth a question. you can find the solution by just searching 'use ng filter in javascript'.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, Would you please let me know how to add $filter as dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `$filter` service in controller like this. you should inject `$filter` service in controller.

```
  app.controller("Ctrl",function ($scope, $filter){
  });
```

in your syntax controller

```
  function Ctrl($scope, $filter)
   {
     $scope.date = new Date();
   }

 var date  = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

```js
// Code goes here

var app=angular.module('app',[])


app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope,$filter){
  
   $scope.date = new Date();
  var date  = $filter('date')($scope.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  
  console.log(date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller=" Ctrl">
 {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you try to use the ng-filter inside you java-script code you need to define it inside your controller so that your controller will be able to detect it.

for example

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $filter) {});
```

here $scope and $filter both are dependency what we will use in our controller.
After that we can any ng-filter either built in or custom, inside the JS controller.
You can prefer this link for more details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Thanks for response, It was helpful.